# Search in test steps in Zephyr

Tags: search, jira, testcase, jira-zephyr

Is there any possible way to search test cases in Zephyr by text from test steps? 
Now it looks like search occurs only in description, summary or specific field.

Comment: this would be such a helpful feature, very disappointing that they don't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the native functionality of `zephyr`, it is not possible to search tests based on the words/expressions of "Test details". Test steps details correspond to the `zephyr` custom field `zephyr` test step. So, these fields cannot be searched using `JQL` or `ZQL`. For the supported fields and operators of `ZQL` use the following link: https://zephyrdocs.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ZTD/ZQL+Reference

Answer (score 0):

For X-Ray, for the JQL query, include "text ~ ..." with "..." being the text you'd like to search for in quotes.  It may work in Zephyr as well.